# How to get when a server was created discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am working on my server command that would show some info about the server. I would like to add the information about when the server was created. Some bots (UnbelievaBoat) have the feature, but I've logged message.guild and I don't see anything that could be the server creation timestamp. I might be overlooking it tho. Is there a way to get that timestamp? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check when a server has been created using [Guild#createdAt](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createdAt), it returns a Date.

```js
if(message.startsWith('!created')) {
    message.channel.send('This server was created on: ' + message.guild.createdAt.toDateString());
}

// OUTPUT
This server was created on: Tue Oct 13 2020
```